# CSS not updating while not active tab in browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using a progress bar for a timer in my game and I set it to go from 100% to 0% over 15 or so seconds. However, during testing since I have two open two tabs to simulate two clients I've noticed that the progress bar will only begin animating in each tab once that tab is activated for the first time.

Now this *probably* won't be a problem in the actual game because all clients will obviously be tabbed in if they're playing but this may not always be the case because some people switch to different tabs while playing games and I don't want their timer to get out of sync. Specifically if I do something like this:

```
$("#progressTimer").css({ 'transition-duration' : "15s" });
$("#progressTimer").css("width", "0%");
```

This sets it to drain from its current percent (100%) to 0% over 15 seconds, but doesn't take effect until after the user tabs in to see it for the first time (and if the user tabs out again it will similarly freeze because when you tab back in you can see it jump instantly.) As a result if someone tabs in immediately and another person waits 5 seconds to see it, then the second person's timer will be 5 seconds behind.

This is most likely done for performance reasons as there's no need to animate things like this which cannot be seen but considering my app is not very intensive as is and will have this one progress bar, I'd like it always to be running, even if the user is not tabbed in. Is there any way to disable this probable browser feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an important timing feature, you should probably be controlling it with an external variable anyway rather than relying on a CSS animation. Somewhere in your control loop you might want to decrement a timer var and then call `$("#progressTimer").css("width", "#{timer}%");`
See: http://jsfiddle.net/3k4egrtm/

Note that `setTimeout()` also has the issue you mentioned. I found somebody else's fiddle that overcomes this using a `Date` object to check how much time has elapsed in between the tab losing and gaining focus: http://jsfiddle.net/qN6eB/

I don't think it's possible to disable that feature--just work around it.